# Autoconf for Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, autoconf

I want to build XZ Utils with MSVC++, but xz utils uses a Gnu Autoconf Script. Is there a way to import a whole autoconfed project into MSVC++, then build it? If not, is there a way to run the Gnu Autoconf script for MSVC++, then after that, just take all the source files, as well as config.h, then build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, not really. You could try installing MSYS and seeing what the support for `cl.exe` is like in the configure script:

```
./configure CC=c:/path/to/cl.exe CXX=c:/path/to/cl.exe
```

Last time I checked, the support was rather immature, but it could be worth a shot. On the other hand, since xz-utils is written in straight C, what does it matter which compiler you use? Build it with MinGW and link against it with visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

FYI XZutils is written in C99 and will not compile under MSVC without massive changes. Just build in MINGW and link to the static lib or dll.